# Unzip a .zip file to all directories that contain a .php file that contains the text “house” inside?

Tags: grep, unzip, xargs

How to unzip a .zip file to all directories that contain a .php file that contains the text "house" inside?

**Something like:**

```
grep -rl --include='index.php' 'house' /directory/path/of_the_index_file* | xargs unzip /directory2/path/file.zip -d /directory/path/of_the_index_file/
```

**CLARIFICATION:** I simply want to extract a simple .zip file with 2 files and one directory, to all directories on the server that contain an index.php file with a specific string inside of its code.

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `xargs sh -c '...'` together with `$(dirname "$1")`:

```
grep -rlZ --include='index.php' house /directory/path/of_the_index_file* \
| xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'unzip /directory2/path/file.zip -d "$(dirname "$1")"' xargs-sh {}
```

Or easier, use GNU `parallel`, which has `dirname` feature included using `{//}`:

```
grep -rlZ --include='index.php' house /directory/path/of_the_index_file* \
| parallel -0 -n1 unzip /directory2/path/file.zip -d {//}
```

Avoid parallelization if you want by adding `-j1` to `parallel`.

If `parallel` is not installed, install it using:

```
sudo apt install parallel
```

---

You might consider running `unzip` once in the beginning to a temporary directory and use `cp` or `ln` inside `xargs` or `parallel`.

Note: For both solutions, I use `grep -Z` together with `xargs/parallel -0` to avoid problems with newlines somewhere in the path. Even if it does not affect you, it's a good habit to take care of it.

Comment: since you used `grep -r --include` over `find` as I did in my parallel answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/551736/123460). Any idea regarding speed? Also could you explain `find-sh` and why you would not need `-n1` in `xargs`?

Comment: Regarding `find-sh`, see `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/is-it-possible-to-use-find-exec-sh-c-safely`. `-I` implies `-L1`, which is similar to `-n1` but based on lines instead of arguments. Unzipping before and using `cp`or `ln` should be faster. `grep -rl` should be faster than `find -exec grep ...` and is shorter to write, but it may be a matter of choice...

Comment: Actually, `find-sh` should be `xargs-sh`, my fault ;-) It doesn't matter much if it works, but it is good regarding useful error messages... But anyways, parallel is easier ;-)

Comment: Thank you pLumo..I tried the code but it showed me the error: 
-jailshell: parallel: command not found

Comment: I thought `parallel` was installed by default in Ubuntu, seems not the case, but you can easily install it.

Comment: Maybe there are some limits - I use the line in Hostgator's shared host probably-limited ssh on port 2222

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually then just used your first code which is using xargs. After I added -o after unzip, your line of code worked exactly as I needed, Thank you once again a lot for a great and extremely quick help! Also Thanks to Fiximan for helping as well.